# Posting image to S3 Conflicting query string parameters

Tags: android, post, amazon-s3, acl

I'm trying to post to s3, but get back an error of this:

```
<Error>
  <Code>InvalidArgument</Code>
  <Message>Conflicting query string parameters: acl, policy</Message>   
  <ArgumentValue>acl</ArgumentValue>
  <ArgumentName>ResourceType</ArgumentName>
  <RequestId>AD52BCA534..</RequestId>  
  <HostId>gdICZHAf...</HostId>
</Error>
```

What does conflicting query string parameters mean?

Answer (score 7):

If you are using an HTML form to upload the file, make sure you have the form's `enctype` set to `multipart/form-data`.  I was receiving the exact same error before including that attribute.

e.g.

```
<form action="https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/" 
   method="POST" 
   enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Answer (score 1):

This was an issue for me when trying to POST a file using jQuery and Ajax. It turned out that the actual file was not transmitted. When I fixed that, S3 stopped complaining.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. I was using chrome rest client to test s3 uploads. My issue was that I had 2 post bodies - one raw and one structured and that cause amazon to send me this error.

I suspect that you probably have multiple post bodies in your request.